# JDBC template.queryForList() not working for preparestatement

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I wrote a Spring Boot code using jdbcTemplate.queryForList(String, Type, String...) method querying from postgresql database since the String formatting would have chance causing SQL Injection.
The code is below:

```
String sql = "SELECT arr.featurecodes FROM featurecapabilitydate,jsonb_array_elements(data->'features') with ordinality arr(featurecodes, position) WHERE data->>'vin'= ? and arr.position in (select distinct arr.position  FROM featurecapabilitydate, jsonb_array_elements(data->'features') with ordinality arr(featurecodes, position) WHERE data->>'vin'= ? and arr.featurecodes->>'featureCode' in(?))";
        List<String> List = readpgjdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, String.class, vin, vin, concatfeatures);
        if(!List.isEmpty()){
            return List;
        }
```

But the returned list is empty. May I ask what goes wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Is the sql query working in postgres?

Comment: Yes, Shweta. It is for postgres